# Preserving HTML Tags from pdf table using Camelot

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, python-camelot

I am currently using Camelot in Python to check this file
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/working-examples/pdf-table/table.pdf
However I am finding that I might be destroying the pdf's original html structure. My question is ; is this a valid method to check for WCAG 2.0 compliance and how do I fix it if it is not.

```
import html
import camelot.cli as cli
#!{sys.executable} -m pip install BeautifulSoup
import wcag_zoo 
from wcag_zoo.zookeeper import zookeeper
from wcag_zoo.validators.tarsier import Tarsier
import tabula
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import camelot
import tkinter
#from wcag_zoo.zookeeper import html

h= html.parser  
path="table.pdf"
pdf=cli.read_pdf(path, pages='all', flavor='stream',split_text=False)


for x in pdf:
    x.to_html("HTML.html")        
    with open('HTML.html', 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        HTML_File = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
        print(HTML_File)
        instance = Tarsier()
        results = instance.validate_document(HTML_File.encode('utf-8'))
        print(len(results['failures']), "failures")
```

Comment: so you are saying that if a pdf has incorrect tags or structure issues they will not be carried over no matter what I try??

Comment: so I have to pull the original html structure from the pdf directly right?

Comment: So how do i get the pdf's html structure and then compare against wcag-zoo, this pdf might not be a great example since it is drawn and the pdf I want to work with is a table with th/td/tr structure

Comment: So I should extract the xml from the pdf using pypdf2 and then pass it to wcag-zoo instead of trying to get htmls tags from pdfs because there are none.

Comment: is there a way to extract the direct abobe interpretation of the pdf  table instead?

Comment: Then how does PAC interpret tables and returns incorrect table headers. That is the structure I need to pull some how

Comment: Thank you I will look into adobe sdk and hopefully find something there, I will let you know if I find something useful to answer this question.